# How to put in a string multiple names from foreign key id and then delete all files with those names from folder?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

How to put in a string multiple names from foreign key id and then delete all files with those names from folder?

I managed to delete 1 row from database and then find image_name of that row and then find file with same name and remove it at the same time with this code

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT image_name FROM imgbox_images WHERE image_id = @id; DELETE FROM imgbox_images WHERE image_id = @id;";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Request["id"]);

con.Open();
String image_name = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
con.Close();

string file = Server.MapPath("~/gallery/" + image_name);
string file_thumb = Server.MapPath("~/gallery/thumbs/" + image_name);

if (System.IO.File.Exists(file))
{
    System.IO.File.Delete(file);
    System.IO.File.Delete(file_thumb);
}

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And then I have a categories table in the database. I certain row in categories table when I press on delete, at the same time it removes all rows from `imgbox_images` that has same `fk_category_id`... But I have no idea how to delete all the files at the same time.

Need help.

This is how I delete categories:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"DELETE FROM imgbox_categories WHERE category_id = @id; 
                    DELETE FROM imgbox_images WHERE fk_category_id = @id;";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Request["id"]);

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Select them before deleting them using a `SqlDataReader`. Then you can use `while (reader.Read())` and delete the files.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...